# Is there a python-notify module for python3.2?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, notifications, pynotify

I have put together a simple time difference python script with whatever I know and it works fine with Python 2.7.3. The script finds the time difference and then sends a desktop notification in Ubuntu using `python-notify`.

```
$ cat timediff.py 
import sys
import pynotify
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
then = datetime.datetime(2012,11,5,8,0,0)

diff = then - now

hours = (diff.seconds) / 3600
minutes = (diff.seconds - hours * 3600) / 60
seconds = (diff.seconds  - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60))

def sendmessage(title, message):
    pynotify.init("image")
    notice = pynotify.Notification(title,message,"/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/important.png").show()
    return notice
sendmessage("Time remaining to exam","%s days, %s hours, %s minutes and %s seconds."% (diff.days,hours,minutes,seconds))
```

However, it seems to fail if I run it with Python 3.2.3. It seems like there is no `python-notify` module for Python 3.2.

```
$ python3.2 timediff.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timediff.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pynotify
ImportError: No module named pynotify
```

Is it possible to use python-notify with Python3 somehow or am I going to have to stick with Python 2.7 until the bindings are ported for Python 3.2?

I found a [mailing list dated April 2010](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/817836) which suggests that `pynotify` may not be Python3 compatible. Has there been improvements on that regard at least?

Comment: You should be able to use the `subprocess` module and `notify-send` to do this in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [here is a `pynotify` replacement](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/notify2).

Comment: in ubuntu, I suggest using this installation method. includes some examples. https://askubuntu.com/a/616996/378854